# How to live sync files between syonology NAS 713+ and Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, sync, ubuntu-18.04, synology, synology-diskstation

I need some way to sync data from synology diskstation to ubuntu server 18.04 and back. I use Synology drive for windows machines and Ubuntu desktops but I have not found any way to install and configure synology drive deb package in cli and I don't want to install GUI to server. I don't want to use rsync with cron job because of high system load. Can't install lsyncd do synology. Is there any way to have real time sync between synology and ubuntu without GUI or am I going have to install GUI on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very interessing tool to sync files between 2 host or more  is SyncThing .

This is open-source and binary are availaible for Synology .

https://docs.syncthing.net/users/contrib.html

Comment: Looks promising, I'll look in to that.

Comment: Thanks. It works exactly as I wanted it to.